# How to pass a value while parsing a nested JSON in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing, codable

I would like to pass the parent area Id to it's children areas while parsing the nested JSON structure as per the attached response, Here I would like to insert 'parentId' for each children which will link to it's immediate parent area,

```
{
  "areas": [
    {
      "id": "271341877549072423",
      "name": "Breeze Office Tower",
      "children": [
        {
          "id": "271341877549072424",
          "name": "100 flinders street",
          "position": 0,
          "children": []
        },
        {
          "id": "271341877549130929",
          "name": "100 flinders street",
          "position": 1,
          "children": []
        },
        {
          "id": "271341877549072425",
          "name": "100 Flinder Stree",
          "position": 2,
          "children": [
            {
              "id": "271341877549072426",
              "name": "Büro",
              "position": 0,
              "children": [
                {
                  "id": "271341877549072427",
                  "name": "Dachgeschoß",
                  "position": 0,
                  "children": []
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": "271341877549130931",
          "name": "100 Flinder Stree",
          "position": 3,
          "children": [
            {
              "id": "271341877549130933",
              "name": "Büro",
              "position": 0,
              "children": [
                {
                  "id": "271341877549130935",
                  "name": "Dachgeschoß",
                  "position": 0,
                  "children": []
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

My JSON Codable model struct looks like,

```
struct AreaModel: Decodable {
    var areas: [NestedAreaModel]?
}

struct NestedAreaModel: Codable {
    let areaId: String
    let areaName: String
    let children: [NestedAreaModel]
    let hasChildren: Bool
    var areaPosition: Int16?
    var parentId: String?
    var projectId: String?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case areaId = "id"
        case areaName = "name"
        case areaPosition = "position"
        case children
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.areaId = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .areaId)
        self.children = try values.decode([NestedAreaModel].self, forKey: .children)
        self.areaName = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .areaName)
        self.projectId = ORAUserDefaults.selectedProjectId()
        self.areaPosition = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int16.self, forKey: .areaPosition)
        if !self.children.isEmpty {
            self.hasChildren = true
            self.parentId = self.areaId
        } else {
            self.hasChildren = false
        }
    }
}
```

Here I am not able to set the parent Id, its pointing its own id always.

Comment: `self.parentId = self.areaId` doesn´t make sense. Shouldn´t you iterate over the children and set their `parentId` to `areaId`?

Comment: There is no limit of how many level of children can be there a particular area, So if we use recursion will that not create a N^(number of child area level), can be upto 10 levels. So would like to do this in Order of N time complexity

Answer (score 0):

As I allready pointed out in the comments you would need to iterate over the decoded children and set their respective `parentId` to the current `areaId`.

One possible Solution would be:

```
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    self.areaId = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .areaId)
    // decode the children to a local var
    var children = try values.decode([NestedAreaModel].self, forKey: .children)
    self.areaName = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .areaName)
    self.projectId = ORAUserDefaults.selectedProjectId()
    self.areaPosition = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int16.self, forKey: .areaPosition)
    // if there are children loop over them and assign your id
    if !children.isEmpty {
        self.hasChildren = true
        for (index, _ ) in children.enumerated(){
            children[index].parentId = areaId
        }
    } else {
        self.hasChildren = false
    }
    // assign to self
    self.children = children
}
```

---

Tested with the given JSON:

```
let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode(AreaModel.self, from: data)

print(decoded.areas?[0].areaId)
print(decoded.areas?[0].children[0].parentId)
```

Result:

```
Optional("271341877549072423")
Optional("271341877549072423")
```

---

Remarks:
Regarding your comment on complexity:
`children[index].parentId = areaId` runs exactly once per child no matter of the level deapth. So this function is (O)n.